# Spectrum +2A power supply capacitors replacement

Tags: spectrum-plus-2

I am new to the world of Spectrums, but I have a +2A which isn't powering up.  I've tested the voltages on the pins of the connector and none of the voltages being supplied were even close.   Given the age of the PSU I was thinking of recapping it, the problem is I can't find any information on the type needed and I can only read the description of the larger ones.  Does anyone know what they are?

Comment: Wet electrolyte capacitors (the ones you'd expect to need to replace) generally have their specs written on them... do these not?

Comment: Noting for completeness: modern PSU replacements are available, and are often smaller, cooler and safer given the age of the originals. Keelog is a seller that I happen to have used, but there are probably a multitude of options.

Comment: They do on the larger ones, but smaller ones are tiny and I can't see anything on them.

Comment: I was thinking of a replacement PSU too, but I thought I give recapping the old first a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a schematic diagram [here](https://www.va-de-retro.com/foros/viewtopic.php?t=2160)

It lists the caps values as:

- C1 - 6800μF 16V
- C2 - 1000μF 25V
- C3 - 330μF 25V
- C4 - 100nF
- C5 - 100μF 16V
- C6 - 100μF 16V
- C7 - 100μF 16V

Compare the diagram for your specific PSU, Sinclair tended to rearrange and re-number the components a lot.

Comment: Brilliant thank you for this.  I'll order those.